# yii2 : attribute being taken as string

Tags: yii, yii2

I am trying to execute this code

```
->andWhere(['like','a.id','b.id']);
```

But this takes b.id as a string to compare with directly instead of comparing it as a table attribute.

Any ideas on how to fix this. I am new to yii2.

Answer (score 1):

Just changed it with

```
->andWhere('a.id = b.id');
```

Thank you.